# Redirects without .htaccess file and "No input file specified" after uploading .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I do not have access to apache files in server. Only possible way for me to change modify possible configuration or rewrite rule is from htaccess file.

To make it simple, the website(eg website.com) has only following pages

- index.php
- page.php
- projects.php

***There is no htaccess file***

When I access website.com/page/ or website.com/page . It redirects me to " *page.php* ".

But after I upload htacces (see below) and access website.com/page(without slash)
 It displays. **No input file specified.**

**Could there be a default setting that has caused this redirection.**

the htaccess file that I uploaded later

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s&().+/-:%]+)$ page.php?url=$1
```

I want following redirection to work

```
 page/about-us
```

redirected to

```
 page.php?id=about-us
```

But this is not working until I use the word other that "**page**" at the left side of the rule.

Comment: Your question title is somewhat misleading. The fact that you don't have access to `httpd.conf` doesn't mean there can't be any rewriterules in there. I suppose there is a rule there that redirects `a` to `a.php` if `a.php` exists where `a` can be any string. It doesn't seem to be the real question though.

Comment: First try to add a `RewriteBase /`. Your first rule doesn't make sense to me. Why would you want to add `/` to your url if you don't want to show it to the user (no `[R]` flag)?